# Print 5 line at a time

Tags: c++

I got a simple cout statement below. And I want to print 5 lines at a time (the output below). I am new to C++. The 3 dots just a symbol to see the output

```
  int count = 0;
    cout << "Print line:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        cout << i << endl;
        count++;
        if (count > 6){                    //if (count % 6 == 0) this is wrong also btw
            cout << i << " ..." << endl;
            continue;
        }
    }
```

The output of the program above is

```
Print line:
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
6 ...
7
7 ...
8
8 ...
9
9 ...
```

Expected output

```
Print line: 
0
1
2
3
4
5
Print line 
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: Be aware that by writing `cout << i...` in two different, but simultaneously executed, blocks in the loop, you are effectively printing the new line number two times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (i % 5 == 0)
            cout << "Print Line\n";
        cout << i << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's always nice to add a few lines of explanation about how the code works.

Comment: This does not produce the desired output as shown by the OP. This code puts the 2nd `Print Line` between `4` and `5`, instead of between `5` and `6` as requested. Change `i % 5` to `i % 6`

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    if (i % 6 == 0)
        cout << "Print line:" << endl;
    cout << i << endl; 
}
```

You need to first check if each loop satisfies the condition i%6==0 or not and then print the number. If the condition is true, then the line will be printed.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this to use an extra loop;

```
        for ( int i = 0; i < 20; i += 6 )
        {
            for ( int n = i; n < i + 6; n++ ) 
            {
                if ( n > 20 ) break;
                std::cout << n << std::endl;
            }
            std::cout << "print line" << std::endl;
        }
```